# How to write a star pattern program in lua?

Tags: lua

The following code is printing the pattern in one line:

```
for i=6, 1, -1 do
   for j=1, i, 1 do
      print("*")
      end
   print(" \n ")
   end
```

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. What have you tried? Where are you running into trouble?

Answer (score 2):

Try This:
Instead of print use `io.write()`

```
for i=6,1,-1 do

    for j=1,i,1 do

    io.write('*')

    end

print( " \n ")

end
```

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Best way to thank is mark this answer as correct.